# Opposite of "ahead"?

Tags: antonyms

I saw this sentence in the dictionary

> **We are ahead by six points.**

I am wondering what the opposite meaning of this sentence is?

Answer (score 5):

"Behind" is the opposite to "ahead" metaphorically as well as literally, including in this case.

Comment: So I can say "We are behind by six points" Is that correct?

Comment: It may sound more idiomatically natural to say "We are six points behind", and in the same way I would word the original sentence in the same way: "We are six points ahead". This is a very minor point.

Comment: Both sound natural to me.  Perhaps it's regional